# MongoDb - Indexes optimization

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-indexes

Indexes optimization:

We reviewed all our indexes on the expensive collection [170M documents] .

We started to removed most on the indexes ; There are 2 main indexes remained [not counting the primary Key]. This trimmed the total index size to 1/3 of its prior value.

In high level we went with the strategy of using “compound indexes”; based on common ground of all properties within the documents used in the queries on the collection.

There are two main use cases used querying this collection.

> **Online**
>   •   There are two dedicated indexes for these two queries i.e.
>   InfoId_1 (equals) and Source_1_StatusId_1_SoundExWord12_1 (equals,
>   equals, in)
>
> **Offline** – we are using [M-R] here. 
>   •   There is a dedicated compound
>   index for all query used in this use case.  All the queries are using
>   most of the fields set in the index. E.g. index name
>   Source_1_StatusId_1_InfoIdHash_1_InfoUpdateDate_1_SoundExWord12_1
>   (equals, equals, range, range, for sort)

Results so far:

After examining the execution plan in MongoDB its seems that the dedicated index for offline operations is rejected in production for the dedicated index for online operations, causing a 270M result scan instead of a 130K result scan (in QA the correct index was selected in most cases).
For some reason is doesn’t use the right index it is unclear why.

More research/tests we’ve done so far:
Once we removed the online index the offline process ; M-R offline process started to work with good performances, thus we are sure it all a matter applying the rights indexes here.

Question/considerations:

There are two alternatives here: here I need you help in either achieving the 1st alertnative or optimizing the 2nd one:

> 1. Adding a hint to the map reduce query (/query+sort) (via C# 2.0 legacy driver) to get MongoDB to select the right index – can’t find
>      any way to do this. Once using the command
>      db.infosoundexpair.find({$and: [ { "Source": { $eq: "XXX" } }, {
>      "StatusId": { $eq: 0 } }, { "InfoIdHash": { $gte: -2147483648 } },
>      {"InfoIdHash": { $lte: -2143862259 } }, { "InfoUpdateDate": { $lt:
>      ISODate("2015-06-04T00:00:00.000Z") } } ]}).sort({"SoundExWord12":
>      1}).hint("Source_1_StatusId_1_InfoIdHash_1_InfoUpdateDate_1_SoundExWord12_1").explain("executionStats");
>      the correct index (defined in the hint) was used.
> 2. Recreating the dedicate online index with a different order of the fields in both the index and the online query prevents the offline
>      process from using this index, enables the online process to use this
>      index, however, does decrease the speed of the online process. We
>      believe that the decrease in speed is since the field we moved from
>      the end of the index to the beginning of the index (the one not used
>      in the offline query, just in the offline sort) is used with contains
>      ($in) instead of equals ($eq) with ~25 potential values, whereas the
>      other two fields are equality comparisons.

Sample document:

```
{
    "_id" : "766574b0-0f3d-4e0a-b979-a6024bf6fbbb/cemcdeomc/vodemer",
    "InfoId" : LUUID("b0746576-3d0f-0a4e-b979-a6024bf6fbbb"),
    "Source" : "OFAC",
    "StatusId" : 0,
    "InfoUpdateDate" : ISODate("2015-06-09T13:55:25.863Z"),
    "SoundExWord12" : "cemcdeomc/vodemer",
    "InfoIdHash" : -547866111
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample document, the `.getIndexes()`, and your queries?  This would make it much easier to reproduce the issue. And what's your MongoDB version?